# When trying to connect my windows form c# application with Entity Framework the DbContext and entity classes didn't load from database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, windows-forms-designer

Using Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Management Studio 2018, I go through these steps

1. Add ADO.NET Data Model
2. EF Designer from database
3. Get the connection from SQL server and choosing the suitable tables.

Comment: Although you think you have added enough information, I can assure you that you haven't. please read [ask] and this [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Comment: No, There is SQL Server Management Studio 2018 @marc_s

Comment: Yes - SSMS - that's the **GUI tool** - ***NOT*** the database version that's typically relevant for all features. Run `SELECT @@VERSION`  in your SSMS 2018 - and it'll tell you what **database version** you're working on. The SSMS version is hardly ever relevant - the **database version** is ....

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64)   Oct 28 2019 19:56:59   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: ) (Hypervisor)  @marc_s